# Splitting an array into two in C

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, split

I am trying to convert some binary code into assembly, but as part of the task, I'm not sure how to get the last 5 elements(of 8) in the array into a new array. As you can see I've managed to created an array for the opCode(the first 3 elements), but am not sure how to get the operand into a new array or edit the initial one.

All help is appreciated.

```
void convert_to_assembly(char bin[])
{
  int i;
  printf("The binary code before spiliting is: ");
  char binary[9] = {'1','0','1','1','1','1','1','0'};
  for(i=0;i<=7;i++)
  {
    printf("%c",binary[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  char opCode[4];
  strncpy(opCode,binary,3);
  printf("opcode: "); 
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    printf("%c",opCode[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

**Output**

```
The binary code before splitting is: 10111110
opcode : 101
operand: ???????
```

Comment: Picky: did you mean only to initialise 8 elements of the 9-array? If you intend that to be used as a string, the last element is not automatically initialised to `'\0'`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think he did because his loop explicitly counts 8 elements.

Comment: @WeatherVane I supposed that's one way to 0-terminate a char array, and thus have a C string. =P. Not exactly intuitive, Doesn't unspecified trailing content zero fill in a length-specified sequence? (missed my coffee this morning, sry if I'm spacing out).

Comment: @WhozCraig mybad: the unspecified element(s) will be initialised to `0` by default.

Comment: @Fraser Steel in the output for the example do you want 11110 for the operand? Why do you have question marks?

Comment: Did you try  `strncpy(bin, binary+3, 5);` ? Not that it's the best idea to copy data into a length-unspecified target, nor is there established termination, but still.

Comment: @abacles yes I want 11110 but I was just trying to show that currently I don't know what to do.

Comment: I would advise to decide whether you want to treat your data as *strings* or as *bytes*. Pretending they are "strings" and using `strXXX` functions on them without actually *making* them valid C strings to begin with, is a bad habit and should be unlearned as soon as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me if I understood you correctly (based on @WhozCraig):

```
void convert_to_assembly(char bin[])
{
  int i;

  printf("The binary code before spiliting is: ");

  char binary[9] = "10111110\0";
  printf("%s\n",binary);

  char opcode[4];
  char operand[6];

  strncpy(opcode,binary,3);
  opcode[3]='\0';
  strncpy(operand,binary+3,6);
  printf("opcode: %s\n",opcode);
  printf("operand: %s\n",operand);
}
```

`strncpy` will copy 6 chars starting at `binary+3` to `operand`, which will copy the next six elements starting from the fourth one.

Comment: yes thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Thanks to @WhozCraig!

Comment: I'm curious, why `opcode[3]='\0';`? I mean, why not to write zero simply as zero? `opcode[3]=0;`?

Comment: `opcode[3]=0;` should work too, I'm just used to writing it as `'\0'`

Answer (score 0):

Since the binary string contains all the information, we can treat the opcode and operand as an overlay view using `union` without creating new arrays nor writing code to tear apart the data:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

union word {
    char binary[8];
    struct operation {
        char opcode[3];
        char operand[5];
    } opvar;
};

void convert_to_assembly(char *bin) {
    union word op;

    (void) strncpy(op.binary, bin, sizeof(op.binary));

    printf("before splitting: %.8s\n", op.binary);
    printf("opcode: %.3s\n", op.opvar.opcode); 
    printf("operand: %.5s\n", op.opvar.operand);
}

int main() {

    convert_to_assembly("10111110");

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> ./a.out
before splitting: 10111110
opcode: 101
operand: 11110
>
```